# JavaScript code wont close dynamically opened modal dialog

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am adding an ID to every modal dialog on my page. When I open my modal window and execute the code, the modal dialog itself disappears, but the shadow is still turned on and I am unable to scroll the page.
I have tried using `$('#ID').modal('hide')` and `toggle` but nothing works. I tried using the `click` method but that doesn't work either.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="{{c.id}}respondDialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" align="center">Respond to {{c.author}}'s comment</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
            </div>

            <form method="POST" name="responseForm" id="respForm" ng-submit="createComment(c, responseText)">

                <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                            <textarea cols="60" rows="2" ng-model="responseText"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" align="center"> 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="responseText.length == 0" ng-click="closeModal(c.id, 'respondDialog')"  >Respond</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my controller.js

```
$scope.closeModal = function(ID, mode){
    $('#'+ID+mode).modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
}
```

Even removeClass wont work.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your JS and CSS references are not correct.